# Coursera jupyterNotebook: revert to the beginning

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyterNotebook from Coursera but see no way to revert everything to the beginning.

[image]

The only option relevant seems to be "Revert to Checkpoint" -- but I didn't save a checkpoint at the beginning.

Does it mean that I am unable to revert to it?

Comment: By default, Jupyter will save checkpoints at the current working directory tree. Look for files with *.ipynb extension and you might find the one you're looking for.

Comment: @user8212173 JupyterNotebook run in my browser without local file. Where do I look for `.ipynb` files?

Comment: If you're running jupyter on localhost, then you will also have another tab that shows the directory tree. You should see the file in that tree. Alternatively, in a cell in your currently open notebook, type `import os` `os.getcwd()` and execute the code with `ctrl + Enter`. This will show the path of your current working directory. You may navigate to this path and look for the file. As a last resort, you can run a full system search for *.ipynb files.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Open your notebook at Coursera
2. Rename it
3. After renaming just add `?forceRefresh=true` to the end of your notebook URL
4. Hit enter
5. You now have old renamed version and new refreshed to default one

Comment: Regarding Step 2 (renaming the notebook), you do this most-easily by clicking the name of the notebook next to the (blue) Coursera logo. This creates a popup. The other way of renaming the notebook is via the open notebook's File > Rename command.

Answer (score 5):

The procedure is described [here](https://learner.coursera.help/hc/en-us/articles/360004995312-Solve-problems-with-Jupyter-Notebooks).

As of July 2019 the `?forceRefresh=true` solution worked for me.

Comment: you need to rename your notebook and then paste forceRefresh. in the url it worked for me then .

Answer (score 4):

These steps will work as of April, 2020:

Rename your notebook and add ***`?forceRefresh=true`*** to the url and press enter. Your entire Jupyter notebook will be restarted. Go to the course week and a fresh notebook will be there.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never - 
This is from the Coursera help section.

To keep your old work and also get a fresh copy of the initial Jupyter Notebook:

1. Make a copy of your Notebook by clicking File, then Make a copy. We recommend using a naming convention such as “Assignment 1 - Initial” and “Assignment 1 - Copy” to keep your notebook environment organized. You can also download this file locally.
2. Click Control Panel, then choose My Server
3. Find the name of your previous file, as well as the new copy of your file.
4. Delete the original notebook file (not the copy) by selecting the checkbox next to the filename. Click the trashcan icon that appears to delete the file.
5. Click Control Panel, then choose Stop My Server.
6. Select My Server to restart.
7. After a few minutes, launch the notebook again from your Course Home. If you get a 404 error while the notebook server restarts, wait a few minutes and try again.
8. After the restart is complete, you will see a fresh copy.

I believe this is a new feature in Coursera

Answer (score 1):

This is the instruction from a course I was taking:

1. In any Jupyter notebook, first save your work by going clicking File -> Download as -> Notebook (.ipynb)
2. Next, click File -> Open. This opens up the file directory.
3. Select the notebook you wish to refresh from the list by clicking the check box next the the filename
4. Click the trashcan icon at the top to delete the notebook
5. Copy this text: ?forceRefresh=true and paste it onto the end of the URL in your browser bar then hit .
   You will see your workspace refresh with the updated copy of the notebook

Answer (score 1):

These steps:

```
1. Open your notebook at Coursera
2. Rename it
3. After renaming just add `?forceRefresh=true` to the end of your notebook URL
4. Hit enter
5. You now have old renamed version and new refreshed to default one
```

Still work as of 05/14/2021

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.

Go to Kernel pull down menu, select "Restart & Clear Output".
Then, the Jupyter Notebook will be restored to initial status, and all output will be erased.

[Please see attached picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUYvN.png)